# Быстрый поиск элемента в списке python

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, list, поиск

Даны два файла: в одном содержится текст, во втором слова и коэффициенты характеризующий эти слова, при том так, что в одной строке только одно слово и один коэффициент. Примерно вот так

`21230 яблоко
 23121 подушка`

В файлах с текстом более 30000 слов. Файл со словами всегда используется один и его содержимое неизменно, но в нем более миллиона строк.

Требуется получить коэффициенты всех слов из первого файла, при этом затратив как можно меньше времени.
На данном этапе имеется список(Пусть он называется firstArr) всех слов из текста и список слов c коэффициентами(Пусть он называется secArr), в котором к слову можно обратиться через

`secArr[word][1]`

а к коэффициенту

`secArr[сoef][0]`

Я никогда ранее не использовал python и не знаю многих аспектов языка, поэтому все до чего я дошел это сделать проверку вложенным циклом

```
for word in firstArr:
   for word in range(len(secArr)):
      if word == secArr[word][1]:
         coef += int(secArr[i][0])
         break
```

Также есть идея сделать то же самое по смыслу, но с помощью

```
for word in firstArr:
   if word in secArr:
      coef += int(secArr[secArr.index(word)][0])
```

Но весьма сомнительно, что это сокращает время поиска(опять же, мне так кажется, может быть это и не так). Быть может есть какие-то более изящные решения проблемы затрат времени на поиск?

Comment: Второй файл - просто текст?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Искать коэффициенты из миллионного списка прямым перебором - это один из самых неэффективных способов. Выборка значения из словаря (хеш-таблицы) является решением вашей задачи.

Из второго файла создайте словарь (dict) и сохраните в файл. Например так:

```
import pickle
# словарь с коэффициентами
d = {
    'слово1': 101,
    'слово2': 102,
    'слово3': 103,
    'слово4': 104,
# ...
}
# словарь можно сделать из вашего "второго" файла, но для этого нужно знать его структуру
dictFile = open('dict.pickle', 'wb')
pickle.dump(d, dictFile)
```

Затем перед подсчетом коэффициентов загружайте словарь из файла

```
import pickle

dictFile = open('dict.pickle', 'rb')
secArr = pickle.load(dictFile)

coef = 0
for word in firstArr:
    if word in secArr:
        coef += secArr[word]
```